# Stopping user-level program to exit kernel module

Tags: c, timer, exit, kernel-module

I have a user-level program that communicates with a kernel module to run a timer. I'm trying to figure out how to get the kernel module to stop the user-level program and exit.

If I do `rmmod mymodule.ko` while an existing timer is running, console outputs the message "ERROR: Module mymodule is in use". I can see that it's in use by one process by doing `lsmod`. I tried putting a `printk()` statement at the very top of my `module_exit()` function in my kernel module to see if that function gets anywhere at all, but it doesn't.

So my question is, if my kernel module `module_exit()` doesn't run when doing `rmmod` with an active timer, where/how can I tell it to exit anyway? I know I need to `del_timer()` too so I don't cause a segfault or kernel panic.

Comment: You do it the wrong way. First you should terminate the user-application, then `rmmod`. Use a lockfile or similar to prevent re-using the module during termination.

Comment: Thanks. That makes more sense to me too, but I think the specifications I have say that the active timer(s) need to be deleted when the module is removed. Is there a way to send a signal when `rmmod` is run?

Comment: Not sure. But if that's given, your specs are rubbish.

Comment: How about adding a way to tell your module "Hey, stop all timers and don't let anyone start any more timers"? Then do that before `rmmod`.

Comment: I need it in the one command though and it doesn't seem to do anything in `module_exit()` so I don't know where I would even put the code to delete them. It was working before I added asynchronous sleep, but now that there's a `pause()` in the user-level program it broke the functionality. I think I need to find a way to kill the `pause()` when `rmmod` is run.

Comment: `timer` itself cannot prevent module to be unloaded. Probably, your module implements some *file*, and application has this file opened. In that case application should close the file before your module can be unloaded.